# Show spinner loading multiple images

Tags: angularjs

I've created a small movie search function that requests data from themoviedb.org in that data are references to posters that I want to show in the search results. In the current situation when I search for a title like `Star Trek` Angular renders a `li` element for each movie object with a title and, a date and a image. The problem is that the images are loaded last which makes the whole experience jumpy. Is it possible to wait with rendering the `li` elements untill all the images are loaded?

In my controller I have a small spinner that shows up during the initial request:

```
    $scope.createList = function (searchquery) {
        $scope.loading = true;
        moviesearchFactory.getMovies(searchquery)
            .then(function (response) {
                $scope.movies = response;
            })
            .finally(function () {
                $scope.loading = false;
            });

    }
```

But since data for the images is just a string the request is very quick. Actually serving the image to the browser from the API takes a while and that causes the list to jump.

Comment: Use some gif image until your ajax call gets all the data

Comment: I have that, but the data if the image is just a string so the requests is very quick but actually serving the images from the external api to the browsers takes a while.

Comment: Use `{{ movieimage || "loader.gif" }}` in ng-Src of Image tag.

Comment: http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2597-preloading-images-in-angularjs-with-promises.htm This looks like a good source.

Comment: You might find Angular-Ladda useful https://github.com/remotty/angular-ladda